# Remove only character between two known strings

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I want to remove the `%` symbol when it occurs between `//` and `/`, but not outside of this.

Here is an example:

```
https://delete%me.com/butnot%this
https://donotdelete.me/test
```

I would use sed, grep or awk.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add samples of input and expected output in code tags in your post. Also add your efforts which you are putting in order to solve your own problem in your post.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
sed 's|\(//[^/]*\)%\([^/]*/\)|\1\2|g'
```

**explanation**

```
s            # substitude
|            # separator
\(//[^/]*\)  # pattern start with // --> save in arg1 (\1)
%            # pattern contains %    --> ignore
\([^/]*/\)   # pattern ends with /   --> save in arg2 (\2)
|            # separator
\1\2         # print arg1 and arg2
|            # separator
g            # global on whole line
```

**test**

```
$ echo "https://delete%me.com/butnot%this" | sed 's|\(//[^/]*\)%\([^/]*/\)|\1\2|g'
https://deleteme.com/butnot%this

$ echo https://donotdelete.me/test | sed 's|\(//[^/]*\)%\([^/]*/\)|\1\2|g'
https://donotdelete.me/test
```